# APEXClass Error

Tags: apex

I am trying to execute the code for the APEX Class below:

```
public class APEXClass {

    //declaring the functions
    private integer VarSum;
    private integer VarSub;
    private integer VarMul;
    private integer VarDiv;

    //declaring the Sum function
    public integer MakeSum(integer VarA, integer VarB){
    VarSum = VarA + VarB;
    Return VarSum;
    }

    //declaring the sub function
    public integer MakeSub(integer VarC, integer VarD){
    VarSub = VarC - VarD;
    Return VarSub;
    }    

    //declaring the mul function
    public void MakeMul(integer VarX, integer VarY){
    VarMul = VarX * VarY;
    system.debug('The multiplication = ' + VarMul);
    }    

    //declaring the div function
    public void MakeDiv(integer VarQ, integer VarR){
    VarDiv = VarQ / VarR;
    system.debug('The division = ' + VarDiv);    
    }

}
```

Below is APEX Code:

```
//creating the object
CalculatorAPEXClass MyObj = new CalculatorAPEXClass();

//using sum function
integer AnsOfSum = MyObj.MakeSum(33,66);
system.debug('The Sum = ' + AnsOfSum);

//using sub function
integer AnsOfSub = MyObj.MakeSub(100,50);
system.debug('The Sub = ' + AnsOfSub);

//using mul function
MyObj.MakeMul(10,10);

// using div function
MyObj.MakeDiv(20,5);
```

The errors I am getting are:

```
Line: 5, Column: 20
Variable does not exist: MyObj

Line: 9, Column: 20
Variable does not exist: MyOb

Line: 13, Column: 1
Variable does not exist: MyObj

Line: 16, Column: 1
Variable does not exist: MyObj
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you copy-pasted, your class name is `APEXClass`, but you tried to use `CalculatorAPEXClass`. All of the errors afterwards are related to `MyObj` not being a valid type, and is therefore not defined.